# minimal polynomial given an algebraic number

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to find the minimal polynomial for the algebraic number $1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$.  My original thought was just let $\alpha=1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$.  The method I use though seems very complicated.  For example, 
$$\alpha^2=(1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^2=1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}+2+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}+3$$
$$\alpha^2=1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+4+2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}$$
$$\alpha^2=4+2\alpha+2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}$$
If I substitute for $\sqrt{2}=\alpha-1-\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{3}=\alpha-1-\sqrt{2}$, I'm still going to end up with $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$.  So I figured I'd square again.  Moving the 4 over makes the calculation easier since binomials are easier than trinomials....
$$(\alpha^2-4)^2=(2\alpha+2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3})^2$$
$$\alpha^4-8\alpha^2+16=4\alpha^2 +8\alpha\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}+24$$
$$\alpha^4-12a^2-8=4\alpha(2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3})$$
From the above calculation I see that $2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{3}=\alpha^2-2\alpha-4$
$$\alpha^4-12a^2-8=4\alpha(\alpha^2-2\alpha-4)$$
$$\alpha^4-4\alpha^3-4\alpha^2+16\alpha-8=0$$
But my question is, how do I KNOW this is the minimal polynomial?  Yes, it is true now, since I constructed it so, that if $f(x)=x^4-4x^3-4x^2+16x-8$, then $f(\alpha)=0$  Do I simply attempt to factor out an $(x-\alpha)$.  In that case, $f(x)=(x-\alpha)g(x)$.  Then I show that $g(\alpha)\neq 0$?

Comment: The degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $4$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: I'm not sure about the proof of Nicolas's statement but I've factorized your polynomial via a guess: [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28x-1%29-sqrt%282%29-sqrt%283%29%29%28%28x-1%29-sqrt%282%29%2Bsqrt%283%29%29%28%28x-1%29%2Bsqrt%282%29%2Bsqrt%283%29%29%28%28x-1%29%2Bsqrt%282%29-sqrt%283%29%29). An intuitive way of thinking about it is that all corresponding roots with alternating signs must also be taken to make the radicals disappear. Much like complex conjugate roots of a real quadratic equation.

Comment: A [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/555557/92124) on another question has a proof that the degree of minimal polynomial is 4.

Comment: @typesanitizer That only shows the degree must be less than or equal to 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the polynomial
$$(y-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3})(y-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})(y+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3})(y+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}).$$
The first two terms have product $y^2-2\sqrt{2}y-1$ and the next two have product $y^2+2\sqrt{2}y-1$. Multiply. We get $y^4-10y^2+1$.
We can now see that $\alpha$ is a zero of the polynomial $(x-1)^4-10(x-1)^2+1$.

To show this is minimal, some algebra is useful. One can show that the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ has degree $2$ over the rationals, since $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. And $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ has degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, since $\sqrt{3}$ cannot be expressed as $s+t\sqrt{2}$ with $s$ and $t$ rational. Thus $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ has degree $4$ over the rationals, so the minimal polynomial has degree $4$.

Comment: I am currently taking a graduate number theory course.  I've not done any abstract in a while, so please give me a bit.  If I understand, $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field and we can extend the field if we consider numbers $a+b\sqrt{2}$, where $a,b$ are rational.  The notation for this new extended field is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.  What do you mean that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ has degree 2?  Is that simply due to the fact that a minimal polynomial can not have degree less than two because of the extension with $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Let $F$ be a field, and let $\beta$ be algebraic over $F$. Then the field $F(\beta)$ obtained by adjoining $\beta$ to $F$ can be viewed as a vector space over $F$. The dimension of that vector space is called the degree of $F(\beta)$ over $F$, and this is the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $F$.

Comment: So since elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}$ look like $a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6}$ and this can be viewed as a vector in a 4 dimensional vector space, the degree is $4$?

Comment: If we extended again, say $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$, then the degree of a minimial polynomial, say $1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ would be 8?

Comment: Yes, except that we have to either show that they are linearly independent over the rationals, or appeal to the general (and not difficult) theorem that the degree of $F(\alpha,\beta)$ over $F$ is the product of the degree of $F(\alpha)$ over $F$ and $F(\alpha,\beta)$ over $F(\alpha)$. Basically just linear algebra here, nothing hard.

Comment: Yes, the degree is $8$. But to do that we need to show that we do get a genuine tower, that for example $\sqrt{5}$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: Another way of showing that the degree $4$ thing you got is the minimal polynomial is to show it is *irreducible* over the rationals, or equivalently that it cannot be factored over the integers. For this it is more pleasant to work with the simpler polynomial in $y$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help

Comment: You are welcome. These things are generally done in a first abstract algebra course, if it is not limited to groups.

Comment: My only abstract course was taken 2 years ago and we FLEW through rings and fields without spending much time.  It was a "modern algebra" course, so a brief overview with less focus on proof.  I will be taking a graduate abstract course in the next couple of years, so I'll get it then.  But I also self learn so this type of thing helps.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

For $~P,Q,R,S,T\in\mathbb Q^\star,~$ irreducible, with $~R\neq T~$ both squarefree, we have

---

$$\begin{align}a~=~P~+~Q\sqrt R~+~S\sqrt T\quad&=>\quad(a-P)^2~=~\ldots~=~K+M\sqrt N~\not\in~\mathbb Q\\\\&=>\quad\Big[(a-P)^2-K\Big]^2=~M~^2\cdot N~\in~\mathbb Q\end{align}$$

---

where $~K=Q~^2R+S^2T,~$ $~M=2~Q~S,~$ and $~N=R~T$.

Answer (score 1):

If just want the know the answer, without knowing why it is the answer, you can use a verified implementation of algebraic numbers. For instance, if you load the [Isabelle](https://isabelle.in.tum.de) library `Algebraic_Numbers/Algebraic_Numbers_Test.thy` from the [Archive of Formal](https://www.isa-afp.org) proofs, you can just enter

```
value (code) "show (1 + sqrt 2 + sqrt 3)"
```

and will get your polynomial as output: the output will always deliver the minimal polymial. Moreover, if you want to test whether a given polynomial is minimal, i.e., irreducible, you can similarly invoke a verified polynomial factorization algorithm to test irreducibility.

```
value (code) "show_sf_factorization (factorize_int_poly [: -8, 16, -4, -4, 1 :])"
```

As a side remark, at the time of writing, the implementation uses resultants and Berlekamp-Zassenhaus factorization to compute the minimal polynomial.